# Espresso test framework matches(isDisplayed()) is throw error

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am very new to Espresso testing. I am trying the following test.

1) Textview is showing or not

2) Textview value is correct

3) perform button click.

I am using following codes.

```
@Test
public void validateTextView() {    

    //To check textview text value is correct
    onView(withId(R.id.textView1)).check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));

    //To check button click is working
    onView(withId(R.id.testButton)).perform(click());

    //To check textview is visible or not
    onView(withId(R.id.textView1)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

But I am getting error on `onView(withId(R.id.textView1)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`

The error is

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Hello World!"

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params={(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x10302f8
fl=LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
pfl=FORCE_DRAW_STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@bc95986, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16908682, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@1a62247, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@8cdb9d, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=63.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->ActionBarOverlayLayout{id=2131165227, res-name=decor_content_parent, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@78bb9e0, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1584, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams@9bc135e, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=147.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->ConstraintLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1584, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@c1ce155, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=2131165288, res-name=secondTextView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=721, height=140, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@1b2076a, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=180.0, y=722.0, text=Second Activity, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>AppCompatButton{id=2131165307, res-name=testButton, visibility=VISIBLE, width=300, height=126, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@d0ba45b, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Test Button, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---->ActionBarContainer{id=2131165193, res-name=action_bar_container, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=147, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams@d613036, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+----->Toolbar{id=2131165191, res-name=action_bar, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=147, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@680e60d, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=573, height=71, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$LayoutParams@60819c2, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=42.0, y=38.0, text=EspressoTestingSample, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>ActionMenuView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=147, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$LayoutParams@75843d3, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=1080.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+----->ActionBarContextView{id=2131165199, res-name=action_context_bar, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@d715b10, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+->View{id=16908336, res-name=navigationBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=126, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@162d609, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1794.0}
|
+->View{id=16908335, res-name=statusBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=63, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@842100e, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:88)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:51)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:297)
at com.example.admin1.espressotestingsample.ExampleInstrumentedTest.validateTextView(ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:42)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:527)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
```

But when I try with `onView(withId(R.id.testButton)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`

I am confused. it is working for Button. But not working for TextView. Both TextView and Button in the same page. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: you mean visibility of textView ?

Comment: @D Prince it is showing or not in the view. Some time the textview will be gone and some times it will be visible in the UI.

Comment: I found the issue. `onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));` This code should be write before button click. Bcoz I navigate to new page while click the button. On that time this code is executed. So in the second page there is no textview. That's why I am getting error. No I moved the code to before button click. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

> **I think this is your solution**

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_view))        // withId(R.id.my_view) is a ViewMatcher
    .perform(click())               // click() is a ViewAction
    .check(matches(isDisplayed())); // matches(isDisplayed()) is a ViewAssertion
```

Conditional logic in tests is undesirable. With that in mind, Espresso's API was designed to guide the test author away from it (by being explicit with test actions and assertions).

Having said that, you can still achieve the above by implementing your own ViewAction and capturing the isDisplayed check (inside the perform method) into an AtomicBoolean.

Another less elegant option - catch the exception that gets thrown by failed check:

Comment: So it will not interrupt the testing. But it will throw error. Right?? Here we are using catch to catch the exception.

Comment: onView(withId(R.id.textView1)).check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));  
Second condition is working or not ?

Comment: The code Within the try block is working for me and that i got the solution from android's official site link is = 
 https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/basics

Comment: I found the issue. `onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));` This code should be write before button click. Bcoz I navigate to new page while click the button. On that time this code is executed. So in the second page there is no textview. That's why I am getting error. No I moved the code to before button click. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error does not come from:

> `onView(withId(R.id.textView1)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`

The first line of your posted error message is:

> ```
> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in
> hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Hello World!"
> ```

So the exception is thrown from your second line. Does the TextView really contains "Hello World"? If you look in the View Hierarchy of the error message, it doesn't seems so. It Looks like your TextView contains the text "Second Activity".

Please check, that the TextView really contains your expected text. Normally simple `check()`s like this should work as expected.

Comment: I found the issue. `onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));` This code should be write before button click. Bcoz I navigate to new page while click the button. On that time this code is executed. So in the second page there is no textview. That's why I am getting error. No I moved the code to before button click. Now it's working fine.